# OpenModelica: how to installPackage(ModelicaServices) for MSL 4.0.0?

Tags: openmodelica

Can anyone explain how to installPackage() within omc/OMEdit?

I'm simulating models built with MSL 4.0.0 and regularly receive a 'scripting notification'

```
[1] 12:23:51 Scripting Notification
You can install the requested package using one of the commands:
  installPackage(Complex, "4.0.0+maint.om", exactMatch=true)
  installPackage(Complex, "4.0.0", exactMatch=false)
  installPackage(Complex, "4.0.0", exactMatch=false).

[2] 12:23:51 Scripting Notification
Skipped loading package Complex (4.0.0,default) using MODELICAPATH /usr/bin/../lib/omlibrary:/home/ben/.openmodelica/libraries/ (uses-annotation may be wrong).
```

OMC & OMEdit install via apt:

```
deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt bionic stable
omc --version
OpenModelica 1.16.0~dev.03-2-g99ae661
```

The exact package name (Complex vs ModelicaServices) changes depending on the model being simulated. Executing one of the installPackage()s in OMEdit -> Tools -> OpenModelica Compiler CLI immediately returns false.

MSL 4.0.0 was cloned from the github release and the source added within OMEdit via Tools -> Options -> Libraries -> User Libraries.

How should a library be registered with the compiler?  When is this needed/what does it accomplish?  Is apt just trailing too far behind to use MSL4.0.0, when current release is v1.19?

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/packagemanager.html
You could remove the MSL you downloaded and then use the package manager to install the MSL 4.0.0. The install package actually does the download from github for you automatically.

Comment: installPackage(Modelica, "4.0.0+maint.om", exactMatch=true); should do it i think.
the package manger is rather new so some issues might exist.

Comment: You could call it from OMEdit CLI and if you get a false call getErrorString() to see if you get any errors.

Comment: @AdrianPop  > installPackage(Complex, "4.0.0", exactMatch=false) => false, >getErrorString() => ""
If I installPackage in a modelica script, it can't find ModelicaServices in global scope.  I originally brought down MSL 4.0.0 because an apt update nuked /usr/lib/omlibray/* ...

Comment: So I reinstalled MSL3.2.3 to /usr/lib/omlibrar and removed MSL 4.0.0, fixing the system omc install.  I no longer see the installPackage() messages, but I don't think installPackages works.  I'd appreciate any general comments on installPackages, as well as any timeline for when OM will move to MSL4.0.0; is there a roadmap somewhere?  Also, is 'uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.2")),' still the preferred way to handle library versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your `/home/ben/.openmodelica/libraries/` and see if Complex is installed but loadModel refuses to load it... There were some other problems with the package manager for our patched MSL version that also might not have been backported to the release branch.

If you use the github version of MSL, you can create symlinks to it in order to tell omc which version it is:

```
ln -s ~/dev/MSL/Complex.mo ~/".openmodelica/libraries/Complex 4.0.0.mo"
```